# Make iOS application run at startup iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, background, voip

I would like to do my app open when iPhone is turned on. I saw that have some people saying can be using voip key in Info.plist but I tried and can't to do that. Do someone have any idea to help me? Thanks

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: search before you ask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864999/make-ios-application-run-at-startup

Comment: here is another, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300815/can-iphone-apps-start-on-start-up

Comment: So... this two links I already read but didn't solve my problem because the first link tell about a accessibility feature and doesn't open the application when the iPhone is turned on. The second link the guys commented it is possible only if the app is running when user turned off their iPhone. If the app was killed by user before turned off, it is not possible to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

In short, iphone does not have any access to permission to edit about "onboot" or "onstartup."
Thus, without jailbreaking this would not be possible.
Check the links I provided on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This would not happen, your app will be active in background through pushkit only when your app dismissed before device goes off.

---

**VOIP** - The app provides Voice-over-IP services. Apps with this key are automatically launched after system boot so that the app can reestablish VoIP services. Apps with this key are also allowed to play background audio.

---

[Even with "voip" present in "UIBackgroundModes" in "plist", iOS App does not auto start after device reboot in iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111249/even-with-voip-present-in-uibackgroundmodes-in-plist-ios-app-does-not-aut)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1